# How did Aharon and his sons manage to handle the Mishkan service by themselves?

Tags: number, kohen-priest, korban, mishkan-tabernacle, temple-service-avoda

In later generations, there were hundreds and thousands of kohanim that could potentially assist with the very full schedule of managing the Mishkan/Mikdash on a day-to-day basis. However, in the wilderness, there was only Aharon and his sons (four and then two) catering to at least 2-3 million people. By the time Aharon passed away there were probably more kohanim - descendants of Elazar and Itamar - but the ratio of kohanim to non-kohanim was still very, very large. How were the kohanim at the time able to keep up with all of the work? I assume that every day there were thousands of different sacrifices brought to the Mishkan, not to mention the rest of the service. Is this incorrect?

Comment: I love the perspective of trying to imagine the reality behind the words that underlies this question. But I have nothing to help build an answer from.

Comment: Where did they get thousands of cows daily in the desert? They barely had quail.

Comment: @DoubleAA They had a supply to start with, but I guess we don't know how many per person. See my comment below on the numbers for korban pesach.

Comment: @DoubleAA I had similar questions about olos r'iyah and chagigah, anytime later. How many animals must Klal Yisrael bring per year, according to the rules? I was unclear if more than one person can share an olah r'iyah, for instance.

Comment: We find that Aharon was able to lift/wave 20000 Leviim in one day. He apparently had  Heavenly assistance to operate really quickly. So the answer probably is that is was a miracle.

Comment: They couldn't even keep up with eating the korbanos during the miluim, and so they had to burn the nosar.

Comment: @Heshy I think that's evidence against: Moshe was angry with them for doing so, and it seems it was for some other reason, see the gemaros about it.

Comment: @MichoelR no, I'm talking about during the seven previous days.  The pasuk in Tetzaveh says והנותר בבשר ובלחם באש תשרפו.  It doesn't say לא תותריו ממנו or anything to that effect.  The implication is that it was just too much for them to eat.  I believe the Malbim makes this point.  The goat on the 8th day is a separate discussion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Were it not for the Malbim, though, I don't know that that would be evidence that anything was actually left over. (I vaguely recall that the Brisker Rav discusses whether they needed to eat the animals entirely, or just something from each animal?)

Comment: In God's many smitings, He killed most of the people who were prone to sinning so they only had to focus in the regular avoda, which didn't scale. In fact, the non levite population declined slightly between the early and late census 603k to 601k.  The only thing that would scale is the korban Pesach but 1) commentators say it was only done once in the desert 2) many people can share a lamb if they eat the minimum amount. Childbirth offerings would also scale but those are spread out throughout the year.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant, with a couple of related questions: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Cf6sxXpjvEI95fmKgtc52ID_mh7-sR36/view?usp=sharing It also has an attempt to work out the numbers for Korbon Pesach, in later generations.
I would appreciate comments and suggestions.

> In the Pesach in Mitzrayim, it seems that each family handled its own Korban Pesach, putting it on the doorposts etc. (see gemara 96a). However, in Parashas B’haalosecha, they brought their only Korbon Pesach in the midbar. There were around 600,000 families, and I don’t know how many joined in a chaburah. Let me use an overestimate and say that every thirty families made a chaburah - and perhaps everyone would get a kezayis. In that case, there were 20,000 Korbon Pesachs.
>
> Here we have a whole different problem: there were apparently only three cohanim, Aharon and his two sons! No rows of gold and silver this time, just three cohanim hurrying to the Mizbeach and back as fast as they could. In the same 270 minutes, they would need to bring 74/minute or one every second. I don’t see how it could be done without a miracle.

Comment: Thanks, Eliyahu!